# Is there a way to stop Angular from picking up a URL change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm trying to integrate a React application (using react-router) into an existing Angular website. I've wrapped the React app up in an Angular directive which loads scripts and renders the React app into the DOM. It also listens for the `$destroy` event on the scope to unmount the React app.

Everything's working pretty well apart from links.
It seems that Angular is automatically binding to every anchor tag in the DOM which is causing the Angular router to pick up clicks on links in the React app. This causes the React app to be unmounted and reinitialised on every link click - this is obviously poor user experience (especially since the React app contains a video player!).

I added a listener for `$locationChangeStart` which checks the old and new URLs and calls `preventDefault` on the event if the two URLs begin with `/reactapp`. This stops the link from being treated like an Angular route but it creates a problem with the URL. It seems that Angular responds to a prevented default on the `$locationChangeStart` event by resetting the URL back to what it was before the event was triggered. I've tried calling `history.replaceState` after this to reset the URL back to what I want (hacky, I know) but Angular seems to recheck and reset the URL on every `$digest` cycle.

So, my question... is there a way to completely stop Angular from picking up the links from the React app?

Comment: I would say this is a very bad idea. Keep React for the view, let Angular do the routing. Using two routers on the same app is just a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks. The Angular website is owned by a client so I can't alter it very much and the React app is an independent app that is integrated into a few different websites. It works successfully with Backbone - it's just Angular that's causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening to locationChangeStart, try listening for routeChangeStart

Comment: Seems to behave the same as not having an event listener at all. The URL changes but the React app is unmounted and restarted which suggests Angular is routing.